# JSON.stringify not working for all properties of object in Typescript

Tags: json, typescript, stringify

JSON.stringify not working for all properties of the outermost object in Typescript.
Please refer to code snippet below:

```
class Criterion {
    '@CLASS' = 'xyz.abc.Criterion'
    operator: string;
    operand: string[];
    field: string;
    constructor(field:string,operator:string,operand: string[]) {
      this.field = field;
      this.operator = operator;
      this.operand = operand;
    }
}

class Filter {
    '@CLASS': 'xyz.ada.Filter';
    criteria: Criterion[];
    constructor(criteria:Criterion[]) {
        this.criteria=criteria;
    }
}

var criterion = new Criterion("a","b",["c"]);
var a = new Filter([criterion]);
JSON.stringify(a);
console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
```

Output:

```
{"criteria":[{"@CLASS":"xyz.abc.Criterion","field":"a","operator":"b","operand":["c"]}]}
```

Expected:

```
{"@CLASS":"xyz.ada.Filter","criteria":[{"@CLASS":"xyz.abc.Criterion","field":"a","operator":"b","operand":["c"]}]}
```

It is not stringifying the @CLASS property of the Filter class object.

[code link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=25&ssc=32&pln=1&pc=1#code/FAYwNghgzlAEDCAnAlgFwKYoPYDtYG9hZjYByAAXgBkBBAZTtNgF4yAPATwC8A6CAIxA8kaTMlykiJLAAdMEVFkQAuWFFQocAcwDcU4rPk4AJqvWatAbQC6ekrABmydGFNqNybXZIhc5gK4giogAFE4upuaeWgA0hogKSspR2nFyCSZmHto2AJQE%20iSoABbIUDzhriyOzq7e9iVlPPGJiNUtwfVFpeUtJu3pECZdAL7AY6CQMLAAYshgGG2E9hTU9IyqpJy8EMYQPHMLmKRdICiLyBCqIhe4Nqd%20GoHBIWeiKFc3YnfW%20cv23SabwuEGYwLEEFG42AwAAbhA2uDsHhWDh0AB3BDnb44EIAIggeJieP4RMseJAeN%20enhbQg1TRmMOixCliR4hw1OAACk6AB5AByPBSWmQDg4IQguT0vhwUCwYHQPDAWC0IV5guF2VF4sluWlQA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in your class filter. Replace the two dots with:

```
'@CLASS'= 'xyz.ada.Filter';
```